# Java user input?

Tags: java

```
  myf = new Finch();
    do
    {
              //menu 4
    if (s.equals("Tap Test")) RunTapTest(s);

            } 

  private static void RunTapTest(String s)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the time interval in which you want the Finch to move backwards: ");

        //get user input for tapBack
        int tapBack = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\n"+"Running: "+s+"\n");
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < testtime)
        {
            System.out.println(myf.isTapped());
            //myf.setWheelVelocities(-255,0,testtime);

        }
                    //I can't set myf.isTapped = true
        if (myf.isTapped()) {
            myf.setWheelVelocities(-255,0,tapBack);
        }


    }
```

Here's the homework question:

> Menu option 4 will determine if the Finch has been tapped on its tail. 
>        If so, the Finch should respond with the spoken words “Thanks” and move backwards 
>        for a user specified time interval.

I'm just trying to fix the user specified time interval (at the moment), and I'm having trouble implementing it.

If I attempt this code

```
if (myf.isTapped() = true) {
            myf.setWheelVelocities(-255,0,tapBack);
        }
```

I get an error on:

```
if (myf.isTapped() = true)
```

Saying

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

I'm struggling on how to get the robot to move backwards if the myf.isTapped = true

Maybe myf.isTapped cannot take boolean values?

I'm using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html for user input (integer in this case)

Also, I think the my.isTapped is from an external Jar file.

Comment: try `if (myf.isTapped() == true)` or even better: `if (myf.isTapped())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
if (myf.isTapped() == true)
```

or even better

```
if (myf.isTapped())
```

`=` means [assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29), `==` means [comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
 if (myf.isTapped() = true)
```

to

```
 if (myf.isTapped())
```

Comment: 'myf.isTapped()' is supposed to be returning 'boolean' then why this extra check. However your not changing anything at all. Correct your answer

Comment: Yes. It's great now. +1 ;-}

Answer (score -1):

In all languages (at least in jS, Python, Java, and C#) `=` means assignment. `==` is the "equal to" operator.

I come from a Python background so:

```
test = True
if test == True:
    print("Hello")
else:
    print("Goodbye")
```

The result from running this code would be

`Hello`